# What is the right way to define a friend function outside a template class?

Tags: c++, c++11, forward-declaration, argument-dependent-lookup, friend-function

If I have a normal class I can "inject" a non-free friend function inside the class. (That among other things can be only be found by ADL).

**case 1:**

```
class A{
  double p_;
  friend double f(A const& a){return a.p_;}
};
```

If instead this is a template class I can do:

**case 2:**

```
template<class T>
class A{
  double p_;
  friend double f(A const& a){return a.p_;} // apparently A const& is a synomyn for A<T> const&
};
```

Now suppose that I need to implement `f` in terms of a class that needs to be defined later. I such case I tried doing this:

**case 3:**

```
template<class T>
class A{
    double p_;
    friend double f(A const& a);
};
...
```

This already gives a warning: "warning: friend declaration ‘double f(const A&)’ declares a non-template function [-Wnon-template-friend]".

Following the advice from the compiler I can do this:

```
template<class T> class A;

template<class T> double f(A<T> const& a);

template<class T>
class A{
    double p_;
    friend double f<>(A const& a);
};

template<class T> double f(A<T> const& a){return a.p_;}
```

Which requires so much more code and I am not even sure it is 100% equivalent to case 2 abov which is what I want, because now I have a truly free function that happens to be a friend instead of an injected friend.

**Can case 3 be modified to be 100% equivalent to case 2 and still have a definition of `f` outside the class? In other words can one inject a friend function that is defined out of the class?**

---

I tried this also, which gives a compiler error:

```
template<class T>
class A{
    double p_;
    friend double f(A<T> const& a);
};

template<class T> double A<T>::f(A<T> const& a){return a.p_;}
```

This answer finds the same solution but doesn't answer the question about case 3 being equivalent to case 2. [What is the right way to write friend function declarations in template class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43696019/what-is-the-right-way-to-write-friend-function-declarations-in-template-class)

Comment: *"A const& is a synomyn for A<T> const&"*: Look at [injected class name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/injected-class-name)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Friend functions have special visibility rule (special case for ADL), so defining function outside the class is different than inside anyway.

Moreover, in case 2, the function is **not** template. even if you have one for every template. So to implement it outside of the class, 
you would have to implement each `friend double f(A<T> const& a);` for every `T`.

The advice is the most close workaround:

- Your function (only the specialization) is friend.
- but your function is template (so deduction should occurs:
  with `friend double f(A<T> const& a, T);` (case 2), `f(A<float>{}, 42);` would succeed
  whereas `friend double f<>(A<T> const& a, T);` would not
  (`T` would be `float` for `A<float>` and `int` for `42`))
- your function is declared outside, so its visibility is *"different"*.

> Now suppose that I need to implement `f` in terms of a class that needs to be defined later. I such case I tried doing this:

Other work around is to declare a private method which will do the job, that allow you to have friend definition inside the class.
That private method can then be defined later:

```
template<class T>
class A{
    double p_;

    double do_f() const;
    friend double f(A const& a){return a.do_f();}
};

// Thing needed by A<T>::do_f

template<class T>
double A<T>::do_f() const
{
    // ...
}
```

---

If the return type is an incomplete type you have to do a trick with `auto` return (this works in g++11 and clang++11).

```
template<class T> class A;
class B;

template<class T>
class A{
    B do_f() const;
    friend auto f(A const& a){return a.do_f();} // not friend B f(...
};

class B{};

template<class T> B A<T>::do_f() const{return B{};}

int main(){A<double> a; f(a);}
```

Comment: So, there is no way to make case 3 equivalent to case 2?

Comment: No, but there are methods to stay in case 2.

Comment: Then I don't understand what you are proposing. Can you please rewrite case 2 following your advice so I can see an example?

Comment: @alfC: Added example to stay with *inlined* defined friend function.

Comment: Ah, excellent. So it seems to be good to make the friend functions "self contained" and at worst delegate to a member function. I didn't say it in the question but I have an extra problem the class that will be defined later is the return type of the friend. I am sure that I cannot return a class that is not defined from the defintion of the friend function (`class B` instead of `double` here).

Comment: I tried `B do_f() const; friend B f(A const& a){return a.do_f();}` and indeed got issues about incomplete type `B`, but `B do_f() const; friend auto f(A const& a){return a.do_f();}` succeed with both gcc/clang.

Comment: that's right for me as well, it works with `auto f(...)` but not with `B f(...)`! I don't know why it works but it does. (good luck with C++98 then). i added this case to your answer if you don't mind.

Comment: Note sure it is valid though.

Comment: I am not sure either. Intuition tells me it shouldn't work. Perhaps it works because the `auto` is deduced much later when the template is instantiated. If it is not valid, I am back to square 1 (square 0 in C++) for the use case I had in mind.

Comment: It is ironic that it is easier to define a member function out-of-line than a friend function.

Comment: Asked [incomplete-class-usage-with-auto-in-template-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52750143/incomplete-class-usage-with-auto-in-template-class) to know validity of `auto`.

Comment: with the years I found compilers (`nvcc`, `intel`) for which `auto` friend will choke SFINAE (the function is not detected). That is one problem of auto friends. I think this happens when the compiler cannot deduce auto in the "first pass".