# incomplete class usage with auto in template class

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, auto, incomplete-type

Is the following code well formed ?

```
class B;

template<class T>
class A
{
    B do_f() const;
    friend auto f(A const& a) {return a.do_f();} // #1
};

class B{};

template <class T>
B A<T>::do_f() const { return B{};}

int main()
{
    A<double> a;
    f(a);
}
```

If I change `auto` in #1 by `B`, I got incomplete type error message.

Compile with `auto` for gcc/clang [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/478d447cfe83bbf1)

Fail with `B` [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/680a5b68f0721352)

Comment: Is this simplified version the same issue? https://godbolt.org/z/9V4fx7  Note: gcc compiles; clang report an error.

Comment: @RichardCritten: Not sure, your function is template, whereas mine is a friend function of class template.

Comment: @RichardCritten, also, Jarod42 code works with gcc and clang.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[[dcl.fct.def.general]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.def#general-2.sentence-3):

> The type of a parameter or the return type for a function definition **shall not be an incomplete or abstract (possibly cv-qualified) class type** in the context of the function definition unless the function is deleted ([dcl.fct.def.delete]).

But [[dcl.spec.auto]/10](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.spec.auto#10):

> Return type deduction for a function template with a placeholder in its declared type occurs when the definition is instantiated even if the function body contains a `return` statement with a non-type-dependent operand.

So with `B`, it's ill-formed by the first rule. But with `auto`, deduction doesn't take place until the function is instantiated... by which point the type is complete, so it's fine.

Note that the first rule only applies to the definition, which is why `do_f()` is okay. You can have declarations which return incomplete types.

---

The above wording technically doesn't apply to this case. We don't have a function template. But the intent is for it to apply to any kind of templated thing. There's a [PR](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/pull/2350) to editorially fix this from:

> Return type deduction for a **function template** with a placeholder [...]

To:

> Return type deduction for a **templated entity that is a function or function template** with a placeholder in its

Which does apply here.

Comment: `f` is not a function template here(friend function of class template) though, but I suppose it is the same.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yeah, that's probably a wording issue.

Comment: Does this mean that without `auto` (C++98) it is not possible to make it work?

Comment: @alfC Defining a non-member friend inline? Nope.

Comment: @Jarod42 https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/pull/2350, fixed editorially

Comment: With the years I found compilers (nvcc, intel) for which auto friend will choke SFINAE (the function is not detected). That is one problem of auto friends. I suppose it is not standard. I think this happens when the compiler cannot deduce auto in the "first pass".